# Importing account circle icon has an error

Tags: import, icons, material-ui

I am trying to import the account circle icon from material-ui icons, but I am getting this error:

> export 'default' (imported as 'AccountCircle') was not found in '@material-ui/icons/es'.

I am not sure what it means. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the package (and the error message), there is no default icon exported from `@material-ui/icons/es/index.js`.

Instead what you should do is either one of the following.

```
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/es/AccountCircle';
/* or */
import { AccountCircle } from '@material-ui/icons/es';
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to import the icon is:

```
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
```